# Différence entre « sûr » et « certain » ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot

J'ai tendance à employer ces deux termes avec une légère différence de sens. Pour moi, « certain » signifie « sûr à 100% » alors que « sûr » signifie « un peu moins sûr que certain ». Cependant, certains pensent que ces deux termes sont des synonymes interchangeables.

A l'usage, cette différence de sens existe-t-elle bien pour vous aussi ou ces deux termes sont totalement interchangeables  (exactement le même sens) ?

A noter que mon dictionnaire ne spécifie pas spécialement cette différence de sens.

Comment: Que disent les dicos ? Rien ?

Comment: J'ai édité ma question pour y répondre.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dans beaucoup de cas, *sûr* et *certain* sont synonymes, mais il y a quand même parfois une nuance. Ainsi, dans le dialogue suivant, on ne peut pas échanger les deux adjectifs :

> — En es-tu sûr ?
>   — J'en suis certain.

*Certain* est légèrement plus fort que *sûr*. J'ai l'impression que *sûr* implique la possibilité d'un doute et la réfute simultanément, alors que *certain* implique qu'il ne peut pas en être autrement.

Il y a aussi *bien sûr* des idiomes dans lesquels un seul des adjectifs convient, ainsi que *certains* sens dans lequel un seul adjectif est *sûr*.

Comment: Je suis également du même avis mais dans ton exemple, n'utilise-t-on pas _certain_ pour éviter la redondance de _sûr_ ?

Comment: @Zistoloen Pas vraiment pour éviter la redondance, mais parce qu'on veut insister et répéter le même mot n'aurait aucun intérêt pour cela. Mon argument est qu'on ne dirait pas « En es-tu certain ? J'en suis sûr », parce que *sûr* ne peut pas renforcer *certain*, alors que *certain* peut renforcer *sûr* (en tout cas dans mon idiolecte).

Answer (score 6):

*Certain* and *sûr* are **not** synonyms, and can't always be interchanged.

**Certain = no doubt is possible**. It's an intellectual notion.
*Il est certain que le système de Ptolémée est erroné.
Darwin et Wallace avaient globalement raison, c'est certain.*

**Sûr = it is reliable**. It's a physical or similar notion.
*Vous pouvez emprunter cette passerelle, elle est sûre.
L'or passait pour être une valeur sûre.*

Comment: Je suis sûre et certaine qu'ils sont souvent synonymes.

Comment: @Kareen Vous vous engageriez sur une passerelle *certaine*? Êtes-vous *certaine de* quelqu'un? (Bien que l'on soit *certain que* quelqu'un ...). S'ils nous paraissent interchangeables, ils ne sont pas strictement synonymes, et leur usage varie (Cf. la réponse de Gilles) : même si je suis *sûr* que vous me comprenez, je ne suis pas *certain* que vous m'approuvez.

Comment: Si les deux mots étaient synonymes, "sûr et certain" serait une répétition.

Answer (score 2):

Je n'en suis pas sûr et certain, mais personnellement, je n'ai jamais noté une telle différence entre ces deux mots.

Comment: Merci de cette opinion.

Answer (score 0):

On peut utiliser cette expression pour distinguer, dans la religion chrétienne, la foi de l'espérance car la si la foi permet la possibilité d'un doute elle justifie de prendre des risques sur son chemin qui est sûr (on y est en sécurité), alors que l'espérance -bien au delà d'un espoir qui peut être déçu- est la certitude de recevoir la récompense au bout du chemin (il n'y a aucun doute) qui permet de tout endurer.

Problème de traduction : Le français est la seule langue qui fait une distinction entre un espoir (qui peut être déçu en cas d'échec) et une espérance (qui est invincible)...en anglais, il faut se contenter de "hope"!

Comment: Quel est le rapport avec la question posée ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).